# how to use "c-style flags enum" from c++ code?

Tags: c++, enums

`ef_vi_alloc_from_pd` function from [this c code](https://github.com/majek/openonload/blob/master/src/lib/ciul/pt_endpoint.c) accepts enum as last argument:

```
int ef_vi_alloc_from_pd(ef_vi* vi, ef_driver_handle vi_dh,
            struct ef_pd* pd, ef_driver_handle pd_dh,
            int evq_capacity, int rxq_capacity, int txq_capacity,
            ef_vi* evq_opt, ef_driver_handle evq_dh,
            enum ef_vi_flags flags)
```

In [this c example](https://github.com/majek/openonload/blob/master/src/tests/ef_vi/efsink.c) we define flags as `unsigned vi_flags` and it works:

```
  unsigned vi_flags;
  vi_flags = EF_VI_FLAGS_DEFAULT;
  if( cfg_timestamping )
    vi_flags |= EF_VI_RX_TIMESTAMPS;
  TRY(ef_vi_alloc_from_pd(&res->vi, res->dh, &res->pd, res->dh,
                          -1, -1, 0, NULL, -1, vi_flags));
```

But in c++ it doesn't work, I have compile error when calling ef_vi_alloc_from_pd `error: invalid conversion from ‘unsigned int’ to ‘ef_vi_flags’ [-fpermissive]`

I've tried to define vi_flags as enum:

```
enum ef_vi_flags vi_flags;
vi_flags = EF_VI_FLAGS_DEFAULT;
vi_flags |= EF_VI_RX_TIMESTAMPS;
```

But this doesn't compile too, when I doing "|=" `error: invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘ef_vi_flags’ [-fpermissive]`

How to use `ef_vi_alloc_from_pd` from c++?

- how to declare `vi_flags` and how to call `ef_vi_alloc_from_pd`?
- how to "|=" `vi_flags`?
- add any options to compiler?

Comment: use a cast when? when I modify flags or when I call function? how to declare vi_flags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may do:

```
ef_vi_flags vi_flags = ef_vi_flags(EF_VI_FLAGS_DEFAULT | EF_VI_RX_TIMESTAMPS);
```

Comment: i have such compile error `expected ‘;’ before ‘vi_flags’
  ef_vi_flags vi_flags = ef_vi_flags(EF_VI_FLAGS_DEFAULT | EF_VI_RX_TIMESTAMPS);`. tried to use `enum ef_vi_flags vi_flags =...` and compile error again `cannot convert ‘ef_vi_flags’ to ‘ef_vi*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘ef_vi_flags ef_vi_flags(ef_vi*)’
  enum ef_vi_flags vi_flags = ef_vi_flags(EF_VI_FLAGS_DEFAULT);`

Comment: Have you `enum ef_vi_flags` defined somewhere ?

Comment: of course, for example `enum ef_vi_flags vi_flags = EF_VI_FLAGS_DEFAULT;` compiles just fine

Comment: @javapowered: Does `ef_vi_flags vi_flags = EF_VI_FLAGS_DEFAULT;` compile for you ? which compiler do you use ?

Comment: this doesn't compile `error: expected ‘;’ before ‘vi_flags’
  ef_vi_flags vi_flags = EF_VI_RX_TIMESTAMPS;` i'm using gcc

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123728/discussion-between-javapowered-and-jarod42).